# Displaying a Game Center Leaderboard in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

I'm working on a game, and I'm looking for help or the code to display a GameCenter leaderboard in my app when a user clicks a button. I have no clue where to start as all of the other answers seem to be for Obj-C, thanks!

EDIT:
The Below answer worked perfectly, but for those wondering how to do this within SpriteKit, simply add the below methods to the `GameViewController` and add a Notification Center Observer

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showLeaderboard", name: "showLeaderboard", object: nil)
```

In your `SKScene` Class, simply call to that observer.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showLeaderboard", object: nil)
```

Just to help out those wondering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` protocol within your class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate
```

This method dismisses the Game Center view when "Done" is tapped:

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

This function includes the code that is needed to display the leaderboard:

```
func showLeaderboard() {

    // declare the Game Center viewController
    var gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
    gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

    gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards

    // Remember to replace "Best Score" with your Leaderboard ID (which you have created in iTunes Connect)
    gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = "Best_Score"
    // Finally present the Game Center ViewController
    self.showViewController(gcViewController, sender: self)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gcViewController, animated: true)
    self.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You can now trigger the function `showLeaderboard` by pressing a `UIButton`:

```
@IBAction func buttonShowLeaderboard(sender: AnyObject) {
    showLeaderboard()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like CeceXX showed, or you can use Easy-Game-Center by DaRkD0G to make it easier. https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift

Comment: I already implemented it the way @CeceXX said, but yes, this looks like it would work too, thanks for sharing!